# Searching for a way to automatically get the name or id of a select box and use it to select the appropriate option from the url. Code given

Tags: php

I have the following drop down list and selects the option based on the url e.g. www.domain.com/?car=Algema&city=Paris

The problem is thatI have 104 different forms and some of them are containg more than one dropdownlist. It is impossible to replace them. Is there a way to replace the `$_GET['car']` with the `$_GET['get the name of select id or name automatically']` ?

Maybe a re-writing regex script that will replace all my php files?

```
<select name="car" id="car" class="select">
<option value="Algema" <?php echo $_REQUEST['car'] == 'Algema' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Algema</option>
<option value="Barkas" <?php echo $_REQUEST['car'] == 'Barkas' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Barkas</option>
<option value="Cadillac" <?php echo $_REQUEST['car'] == 'Cadillac' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Cadillac</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something less repetitive like this:

```
function makeSelect($name, $options) {
    foreach ($options as &$option) {
        $selected = isset($_GET[$name]) && $_GET[$name] == $option;
        $option = sprintf('<option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s</option>',
                          htmlspecialchars($option),
                          $selected ? ' selected="selected"' : null);
    }

    return sprintf('<select name="%1$s" id="%1$s" class="select">%2$s</select>',
                   htmlspecialchars($name),
                   join($options));
}

$options = array('Algema', 'Barkas', 'Cadillac', …);
echo makeSelect('car', $options);
```

You can probably automate the extraction of the option names into the array format using a Regex, but you'll still have to confirm everything by hand at least.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I have to change the array with the values right? How can I use this `<option value="Algema">Algema</option>` to extract the values in the form of your array ?

Comment: A regex like `/<option\s+value="(\w+)".+?<\/option>/` → `'$1', ` should probably do it, but since you'll have to make the substitution with your text editor or other tool of choice, that may differ. Learn: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I have accepted your answer, thank you for that.. I would be really thankful if you modify your code and add a regex that gets the `<option value="Algema">Algema</option>....`. By this, I will not copy paste around 200 different dropdown lists with about 10 options each. Instead I will use a program for mass text input to paste your code in the front and end of the lists.